# SIFR 3 text resizing to fit width

Tags: sifr

I'm using sifr 3 and trying to fit h1's on a single line but within a set width of 400px.  By default, if there's too much text, it drops onto the next line.  I've used forceSingleLine: true but then the text just stretches across the 400px width.  Is there a method which will resize the text to fit in the width AND stay on a single line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was the behavior of sIFR 2, which resulted in inconsistent font sizes. This has been fixed in sIFR 3, so what you're trying to achieve is only possible in sIFR 2.

Answer (score 0):

But what about the sIFR3 attribute "fitExactly", then?