# Why sifr text's swf takes more width than actual text?

Tags: html, xhtml, sifr, sifr3

I think if we can match swf size with original text width's then rendering will be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font-replacement flash generated by sIFR takes the same space as the replaced HTML element. So if for example the text you are replacing is inside of an `h1` tag, sIFR will take up the whole space of that `h1` element and **not** the space of the text inside of it.

I guess the element that you are replacing has a width of 100%. You can set a border on it (`style="border: solid 1px black;"`) so you can see the bounds of the element.

Comment: @ u understood exact what i was asking. the thing is if H1 (which is block level element) takes full available width in web page but it does not increase page rendering time but if we use sIFR , it generates swf movie which causes of length page rendering. if there a option in sIFR to make swf width same as actual text , it would be better.

Comment: You could set style="display:inline;" on the H1 tag so it becomes an inline element.

Or you could use a SPAN tag with an ID and apply sIFR to that ID.

Comment: I don't think this will speed up the rendering though! sIFR will always take longer to render than simple HTML, because it uses javascript and flash...

Answer (score 0):

Getting SIFR to be rendered in the exact layout (except for the font) is always challenging.

You might get some hints/helps here:
[SO - SIFR 3 text resizing to fit width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797244/sifr-3-text-resizing-to-fit-width)
[sIFR Width Problem](http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?id=15013)
[Font Sizing with sIFR](http://novemberborn.net/sifr3/font-sizing)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having difficulty with sIFR, you might try Cufon instead. It's very easy to integrate and gives very good results.

To be on the right side of the law, you have to make sure that the fonts you use allow web embedding. You can read more about it here -

- Cufon home: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/
- Cufon documentation: https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki

You should also look into Typekit here. Typekit is an elegant, although not free, solution from Jeff Veen and Small Batch:

- http://typekit.com/

Answer (score 0):

sIFR text might take up more space (or less!) because the font is different than the HTML font. You can influence the width of the HTML text using `letter-spacing` in a CSS rule prefixed with `.sIFR-active`.

Comment: letter spacing will decrease the spacing between letter but i'm asking about space after text